# Apache2 AddDescription match exact file/directory name

Tags: apache

I'm trying to add a description to the (apache generated) directory listing. However I can't figure out a way to get the description text to only be applied for an exact match of the file/directory name.

For example, if I have the following directory/file structure

```
phpinfo2.php
phpinfo/
phpinfo.php
another_file.php
```

and I apply the directive:

```
AddDescription "PHP" phpinfo
```

This matches 3 of the 4 files/directories, as follows:

```
phpinfo2.php         PHP
phpinfo/             PHP
phpinfo.php          PHP
another_file.php
```

However what I'd really like is:

```
phpinfo2.php
phpinfo/             PHP
phpinfo.php
another_file.php
```

as I only want the AddDescription directive to match the exact file/directory name.

The docs (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#adddescription) say that "File is a file extension, partial filename, wild-card expression or full filename for files to describe." - so it's not possible to only match a full file/directory name?

Any help much appreciated, or if there may be alternative ways to achieve what I'd like. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
AddDescription "&nbsp;" *?phpinfo
AddDescription "&nbsp;" phpinfo?*
AddDescription "PHP" phpinfo
```

Apache applies the first matched rule and skips any following rule. The trick here is to use `"&nbsp;"`, which is the default content for a file/folder that doesn't match anything, to nullify any file/folder that contains `phpinfo` but isn't exactly `phpinfo`, so that only a file/folder exactly named `phpinfo` gets the description applied.

Note that you cannot use `AddDescription "" ...` because Apache does not allow an empty string parameter and will throw an error.

ref: [Apache 2.4 doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#adddescription)

Comment: Two simplifications: (1) Since Apache allows you to specify multiple file specs on an AddDescription line, you can combine the first two AddDescription lines, and (2) you can also just use a quoted blank instead of a quoted &nbsp;.

Comment: A third simplification: Since Apache matches partial file names, you can omit the asterisks. "?" works just like "?*"

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you can do it by "first hit match".

So, directives should look like this:

```
AddDescription " " *.php
AddDescription "PHP" phpinfo
```